# Google script to Save open Sheet to file

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm in the process of learning about Google Scripts and Javascripts, I love coding solutions but need to know a lot more so apologies for being a little slow.

I know how to use script in google docs but I am not sure yet on how to construct many things, I am learning from examples and trying to understand from what I find.

I have a scenario where I have a google sheet that I would like to use as a template so a user can enter in data in all the fields then click a button to save the whole sheet as a file (the same as going File > Save As) but use an ID number in a field as the name of the document when saving and place these in a folder within the same directory as the master template. After clicking the save button the sheet would need to reset to original ready for another entry.

The user can open up the saved document and make changes if required.

I haven't been able to find examples I can quite understand to make them work so any assistance would be great, even pointers for resources that would make it easier for me to learn

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is to general for Stack Overflow.  If you want general advice about how to do something with Apps Script, try the [Apps Script Group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: If my answer matches what you need, maybe you could "accept" it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, create a folder in your drive named **MyTargetFolder**. Put your template spreadsheet in, fill "**ID**" to first row as a filed, any number as value to second row.

all script you need are below :

```
// create a custom menu to add Save feature.   
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Feature')
    .addItem('Save Spreadsheet', 'saveSpreadSheet')
    .addToUi();
}
```

Then implement save feature.

```
function saveSpreadSheet() {

  var thisSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  /*
   What first row and second row look like :
         -----
        | ID  |
         -----
        | 123 |
         -----
  */
  var id = thisSpreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, 1, 1).getValue();

  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var destFolder = '';
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    if ( folder.getName() == 'MyTargetFolder' ) {
      destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder.getId()); 
    }
  }

  DriveApp.getFileById(thisSpreadSheet.getId()).makeCopy(id, destFolder); 

  // recover the template
  thisSpreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, 1, 1).setValue(' ');

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .alert('Check your Drive to make sure file have been saved');
}
```

All Google app script API that about spreadsheet are well documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).

And API about [Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#).